# Use result of 'IF' in 'SELECT' in 'WHERE' clause in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

We have the following query:

```
SELECT
        foo_id,
        IF (( SELECT
            COUNT(foo_mapping_id) 
        FROM
            foo_bar_mappings,
            bar
        WHERE
            foo_mapping_foo_id = foo_id
            AND foo_mapping_bar_id = bar_id ) > 0,
        foo_status,
        'inactive') AS foo_status
    FROM
        foo
    WHERE
        foo_status = 'inactive'
```

When we run it, we get an empty result, because `foo_status` is not equal to `inactive` (while there are rows that satisfy the `IF`). `foo_status` is a column that exists in the `foo` table, but we want to "overwrite" it.

How would we change this query so we can use the `foo_status` as returned by the `IF` in our `WHERE` clause? Obviously this query has been simplified to make the question easier to ask and understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use a column alias in a `where` clause.  MySQL *does* extend the `HAVING` clause so it can be used instead:

```
having foo_status = 'inactive'
```

Note:

I would write the query as:

```
SELECT f.foo_id,
       (CASE WHEN (EXISTS (SELECT 1
                           FROM foo_bar_mappings fb JOIN
                                bar b
                                ON fb.foo_mapping_bar_id = b.bar_id
                           WHERE fb.foo_mapping_foo_id = f.foo_id
                          ) 
             THEN foo_status
             ELSE 'inactive'
         END) AS new_foo_status
FROM foo f
HAVING new_foo_status = 'inactive';
```

Notes:

- `EXISTS` is more efficient than `COUNT(*)` in this context.
- I prefer `CASE` to `IF()` because the former is ANSI standard.
- I am uncomfortable using a column alias that has the same name as a real column.  This can be confusing when the alias is used.

Comment: But `having` without any `group by`. does it make sense?

Comment: @Rahul . . . It does in MySQL because of this extension.  I think the extension exists because MySQL materializes subqueries (which other databases do not necessarily do), so this is a way to do filtering without using a subquery.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested in other answer you can use the column alias in `HAVING` clause but I see you have no `GROUP BY` in your posted query. In such case, you can use the aliased column in a outer query like

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT
        foo_id,
        IF (( SELECT
            COUNT(foo_mapping_id) 
        FROM
            foo_bar_mappings,
            bar
        WHERE
            foo_mapping_foo_id = foo_id
            AND foo_mapping_bar_id = bar_id ) > 0,
        foo_status,
        'inactive') AS foo_status
    FROM
        foo ) xxx
    WHERE
        foo_status = 'inactive'
```